# Minizinc unexpected syntax error

Tags: minizinc

What does the following error mean(and I don't even have line no.83 either in .mzn or .dzn:

Error: invalid integer literal in line no. 83

Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting FZ_INT_LIT in line no. 83

Is it because the numbers in my arrays are too large for the solver to handle?

Comment: The error refers to the line number of the generated FlatZinc (.fzn) file. However, it's much easier to help you if you show the MiniZinc model.

Comment: I ran it from the cmd and got a more detailed error message: "the integer literal does not fit into 32 bits" - so it means I can't run the model with the data I have? Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit machine (or version of MiniZinc)? The error indicates that some number is to large. If possible try with a 64-bit machine (or version of MiniZinc). Also, if you have some "var int" domain, check if you can state a more restricted domain.

Comment: My machine is 64-bit windows but can't really get 64-bit Minzinc for windows. I installed it on Linux but Miniznc didn't run for me due to the Linux version I had. As the size of the array numbers are unpredictable so can't use a more restricted domain at the moment. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Take a look at this github issue: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/260